# SwiftUI - variable bound to picker does not match selected value of the picker

Tags: foreach, swiftui, picker

In this code repDuration is an int and whenever I select a value in the picker repDuration will be that same value minus 1 despite the tag being equal to the number. When I make repDuration a String instead of an Int the problem vanishes, can someone explain how I can get the values to match if I want to keep repDuration as an Int?

```
Picker("Duration", selection: self.$item.repDuration) {
         ForEach(1..<366) { number in
            Text("\(number)").tag(number)
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need your iterator to conform to the .Identifiable protocol, or specify an id in the ForEach call like this:

```
Picker("Duration", selection: self.$item.repDuration) {
     ForEach(1..<366, id: \.self) { number in
        Text("\(number)").tag(number)
     }
}
```

Without that, swift is returning the index of your range sequence, rather than the value.